# CSS3 transition not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I've got a simple div setup that transitions up when you swipe up the screen, and it works fine on my desktop, but I can't get the transition to work on my mobile (also tried on an Android emulator).

I thought it was a problem with the swipe at first (using TouchSwipe), but then I tested it with a button and the transitions still aren't working. To give some background, it's an Angular app, and this is part of a template for Angular. I don't think there's any conflict between any of this...

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage" class="swipe-container">
    <div class="section">

        <button id="btnOpen" class="btn btn-primary">Open</button>

        <div class="swipeMenu">
            Text
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.swipeMenu {
    height: 45vh;
    width: 90vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {

        $("#btnOpen").click(function() {
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease");
      $('.swipeMenu').css("-moz-transition", "-moz-transform 0.3s ease");
      $('.swipeMenu').css("-o-transition", "-o-transform 0.3s ease");
      $('.swipeMenu').css("transition", "transform 0.3s ease");
      $('.swipeMenu').css("transform", "translateY(-40vh)");
        });

    //Enable swiping...
    $(".swipe-container").swipe( {
      //Generic swipe handler for all directions
      swipeUp:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-moz-transition", "-moz-transform 0.3s ease");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-o-transition", "-o-transform 0.3s ease");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("transition", "transform 0.3s ease");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("transform", "translateY(-40vh)");
      },
      swipeDown:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-moz-transition", "-moz-transform 0.3s ease-in");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("-o-transition", "-o-transform 0.3s ease-in");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("transition", "transform 0.3s ease-in");
        $('.swipeMenu').css("transform", "translateY(40vh)");
      },
      //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
      threshold: 80
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you please post a working jsfiddle? I put your code into [one](http://jsfiddle.net/aa68x0xh/), but am not seeing anything.

Comment: I think `"-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease"` should be `"-webkit-transition", "all 0.3s ease"`, and similarly throughout.

Comment: But I just remembered that jQuery's `.css()` method will automatically add prefixes as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a better idea to put all of those Javascript CSS changes into a single CSS class, then use jQuery `addClass` instead, especially since those CSS values are repeated several times throughout your code.

Despite that, you also want to add vendor prefixes for that `transform` property, specifically for -webkit. That's probably why the animation isn't working on Android.

Comment: Moving them to a separate class seemed to allow it to work on mobile, no idea how that works but it seemed to do the job. I've changed the transitions to something like this for all of them: `-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;` and `-webkit-transform: translateY(-40vh);`, I think I've done this correctly as I haven't seen any issues since. But again, not sure why it works!

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `transition` properties on `onclick` event! Set them in css. Then on click, do just the transform. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: This didn't work, but I'll give the `classList` answer below a try.